# parsing XML in TSQL and fill with NULL when attribute is xsi:nil

Tags: xml, t-sql, xpath, null, xquery

I've worked on this a while now.

```
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS XMLOpenXML
    Create Table XMLOpenXML (XMLData XML)
    INSERT INTO XMLOpenXML
    SELECT '<rootTag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Parameter>
        <Migrationsobjekt></Migrationsobjekt>
        <Datenbankname>dav30</Datenbankname>
        <StartZeitstempel>18.06.2019 09:30:05</StartZeitstempel>
      </Parameter>
      <Liste>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>01 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123                                                                 </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>02 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   zeichen                                                          </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>03 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   12312345                          </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="1" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="1" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="1" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="1" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="1" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="1" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="1" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>05 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   86                                                               </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="1" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="1" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="1" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="1" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="1" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="1" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="1" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>06 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   3455                               </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>07 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   98765                                                 </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>08 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   Bezeichnungs 123123             </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>09 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   2432343           </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>10 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   zeichen                                            </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>11 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   bezeichen                                       </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>12 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   12345                                    </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>13 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   zeich                       </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>15 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   sdsddsd                                                </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>20 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   dedaz                                                               </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>21 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   gt            </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>25 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>Bezeichnungs 123123   zttr                                 </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>27 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>fdsBezeichnungs 123123                                 </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>29 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>1314Bezeichnungs 123123                                  </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Kennzeichen>00 </Kennzeichen>
          <Schluessel>30 </Schluessel>
          <Bezeichnung1>234rwBezeichnungs 123123                                   </Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung2>
          <Bezeichnung3 xsi:nil="true" ></Bezeichnung3>
          <Status>1</Status>
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
          <Vermerk3 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk3>
          <Vermerk4 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk4>
          <Vermerk5 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk5>
        </plan>
      </Liste>
    </rootTag>'
    /****** Object:  Table [dbo].[IMP_PLEPL_KO]    Script Date: 22.11.2019 16:14:17 ******/
    SET ANSI_NULLS ON
    GO

    SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
    GO
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS [dbo].[IMP_]
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[IMP_](
        [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [Planjahr] [int] NULL,
        [Kennzeichen] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Bezeichnung1] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Bezeichnung2] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Bezeichnung3] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Status] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
        [Vermerk1] [int] NULL,
        [Vermerk2] [int] NULL,
        [Vermerk3] [int] NULL,
        [Vermerk4] [int] NULL,
        [Vermerk5] [int] NULL,
        [Schluessel] [nvarchar](max) NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
    GO
    DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)
    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES (DEFAULT 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance')  
    SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLOpenXML
    EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML, '<rootTag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>'



    INSERT INTO [dbo].[IMP_] (
          [Planjahr]
          ,[Kennzeichen]
          ,[Bezeichnung1]
          ,[Bezeichnung2]
          ,[Bezeichnung3]
          ,[Status]
          ,[Vermerk1]
          ,[Vermerk2]
          ,[Vermerk3]
          ,[Vermerk4]
          ,[Vermerk5]
          ,[Schluessel])
    SELECT *
    FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/rootTag/Liste/plan', 1)
    WITH 
    (
        Planjahr int ,
        Kennzeichen nvarchar(max) ,
        Bezeichnung1 nvarchar(max) ,
        Bezeichnung2 nvarchar(max) ,
        Bezeichnung3 nvarchar(max) ,
        Status nvarchar(max) ,
        Vermerk1 int ,
        Vermerk2 int ,
        Vermerk3 int ,
        Vermerk4 int ,
        Vermerk5 int ,
        Schluessel nvarchar(max) 
    )

    EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
    GO
```

This code creates a table with NULLs in every column. 
[image]

If I change the argument of -

`FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/rootTag/Liste/plan', 1)`

to 
`FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '/rootTag/Liste/plan', 2)`

The table is filled with the correct content-values, **BUT** with 0 instead of NULL for [int] objects and "" instead of NULL for `[nvarchar]`

Whats wrong in my approach? I'd like to fill my table with the XML content and IF there is a `xsi:nil attritube`, it should be filled with **NULL**.

Thanks in advance,
ITsab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some things to state first:

- For your next question: Please try to reduce the input to the needed minimum. I've done this for you below.
- The approach with `FROM OPENXML` (together with the stored procedures to prepare and to remove a document) is outdated and should not be used any more.

Some things should be clear in advance: An empty string will be taken as `0` when read as `int`:

```
SELECT CAST('' AS INT)
```

You can try something along this:

I assume, that your XML is living in a XML variable, but this works similar with a table column too:

```
DECLARE @YourXml XML=
N'<rootTag xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Parameter>
        <Migrationsobjekt></Migrationsobjekt>
        <Datenbankname>dav30</Datenbankname>
        <StartZeitstempel>18.06.2019 09:30:05</StartZeitstempel>
      </Parameter>
      <Liste>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Bezeichnung1>First Plan</Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Vermerk1>1</Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
        </plan>
        <plan>
          <Planjahr>2018</Planjahr>
          <Bezeichnung1>Second Plan</Bezeichnung1>
          <Bezeichnung2 xsi:nil="true" />
          <Vermerk1 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk1>
          <Vermerk2 xsi:nil="true" ></Vermerk2>
        </plan>
      </Liste>
    </rootTag>'
```

The query:

```
SELECT @yourXml.value('(/rootTag/parameter/Migrationsobjekt/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Migrationsobjekt
      ,@yourXml.value('(/rootTag/parameter/Datenbankname/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Datenbankname
      ,@yourXml.value('(/rootTag/parameter/StartZeitstempel/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS StartZeitstempel
      ,pl.value('(Planjahr/text())[1]','int') AS Planjahr
      ,pl.value('(Bezeichnung1/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Bezeichnung1
      ,pl.value('(Bezeichnung2/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Bezeichnung2
      ,pl.value('(Vermerk1/text())[1]','int') AS Vermerk1
      ,pl.value('(Vermerk2/text())[1]','int') AS Vermerk2
FROM @yourXml.nodes('/rootTag/Liste/plan') A(pl);
```

The idea in short:

- The general `<parameter>` values (which exist only once in your XML) we can read directly from the variable.
- We use `.nodes()` to get all the `<plan>` elements as a derived set.
- We can use `pl.value()` in order to fetch values from within such a `<plan>` fragment.
- Using `/text()` will not return an empty string (which would occur as `0`), but will return as `NULL`. A missing `text()` node is taken as `NULL`, while an element without content is returned as an emptry string (see above).

### UPDATE

An alternative was a predicate like here

```
      ,pl.value('(Vermerk1[empty(@xsi:nil)])[1]','int')
```

This will return a NULL, whenever the element `<Vermerk1>` has got the attribute `@xsi:nil`.

or this

```
      ,pl.value('(Vermerk1[not(@xsi:nil="true")])[1]','int')
```

This looks for elements, where this attribute is not true.

Remark: In both alternatives I'd still add the `/text()` after the predicate...